Two isotropic subspaces in a symplectic vector space
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$, let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $V$, and let $\omega(-,-)$ be a symplectic bilinear form on $V$.  In other words, $\omega(-,-)$ is an alternating form that is nondegenerate in the sense that it identifies $V$ with its dual $V^{\ast}$.
Now let $I,J \subset V$ be isotropic subspaces, that is, subspaces on which $\omega$ vanishes identically.  The form $\omega(-,-)$ then induces symplectic forms on $I^{\perp}/I$ and $J^{\perp}/J$.  Define a map $f\colon I^{\perp} \cap J^{\perp} \rightarrow I^{\perp}/I \oplus J^{\perp}/J$ via the formula $f(x) = (x,-x)$.  The image of $f$ is then an isotropic subspace of $I^{\perp}/I \oplus J^{\perp}/J$.
A paper I am reading claims that the image of $f$ is a Lagrangian, that is, that $\text{Image}(f)^{\perp} = \text{Image}(f)$.  I can't figure out how to prove this.  Can anyone help?

One probably-easy way to see it is to count dimensions.

The dimension here that I don't know how to count is that of $I^{\perp} \cap J^{\perp}$.  It's not even clear to me that it only depends on the dimensions of $I$ and $J$ and $I \cap J$.

$\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}$If you know a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space is isotropic, to prove it is Lagrangian, it suffices to show it has half the total dimension. The rest is an easy linear algebra exercise:
$$\dim \im(f)=\dim(I^\perp\cap J^\perp)-\dim \ker(f)=\dim((I\oplus J)^\perp)-\dim(I\cap J)=\dim V-\dim(I\oplus J)-\dim(I\cap J)=\dim V-\dim I-\dim J=(\dim I^\perp/I+\dim J^\perp/J)/2.$$
By the way, you need to use the symplectic form induced by $-\omega$ on the $J^\perp/J$ factor for $f$ to have isotropic image. Also, I think this question is more suitable for MathStackExchange.

Note that I used the antidiagonal embedding taking $x$ to $(x,-x)$.  That's why I don't need $-\omega$ on that factor.

The negation signs cancel out: $\omega(-x,-y)=\omega(x,y)$.

Ah, that's a good point.  I was being overly clever in attempting to avoid introducing more notation.

If you find a question more appropriate for MSE, then it is better to vote to migrate (or I think you can flag if you don't yet have privileges to cast such a vote) and answer there, rather than answering in what you feel to be the wrong place.

@LSpice I'm new to this site. Thanks for letting me know!
